# Drupal 7 displaying different user content

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have searched and searched and cannot find a solution to my specific problem...

I have a site that users join, and can upload their own videos. I crated a specific video type to handle this upload.

Other users can log in and see this content, they get to the content by clicking on a "profile" link for a specific user, and then it should display all the videos that user uploaded. Currently all I can get to work is display ALL of that content type, or none... I cannot figure out how to just get the user being looked for.

In my URL i have the user name being sent, because other info on the profile page that loads is driven off of that ( looked up in mysql tables and displayed with PHP).

As I mentioned I have a filter that limits to playervideo ( which is my content type) and that works, but as mentioned it displays all not just the user I am looking for.

any help would be much appreciated!!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "How do I make a page for all users that lists content authored by a specific user"

I'd do this with the Views module.

1. Add a view for all your nodes.
2. Then add a "relationship" for "Content: Author".
3. Now add a "contextual filter" for the field "user: uid" with a default argument the userid from the URL.

Or you could try to add a contextual filter of "Content: User posted or commented" with the default value as the UID from the URL.

Cheers!